# How to Rename the "Desktop" Folder?

Tags: windows, shell

I have a Swedish version of Microsoft Windows 7 (64-bit). In my user folder, that is, in `C:\Users\Andreas Rejbrand\`, there are folders `Desktop`, `Documents`, `Pictures`, `Music`, `Downloads`, etc. However, in the UI, these are displayed as `Skrivbord`, `Dokument`, `Bilder`, `Musik`, `Hämtade filer`, etc.

Now, [while doing research for a SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970692/how-to-display-create-shortcut-dialog), I managed (programmatically) to rename the `Desktop` folder to `OS (C).lnk`. To fix the folder (which always is empty in my case), I removed it, logged out, and logged in again. Then Windows recreated the folder. But, now it is called `Skrivbord` (and not `Desktop`, as before), and so some of my `bat` files need to be changed. Actually, I would prefer the folder to be named `Desktop` (but, of course, to be displayed as `Skrivbord`), for a variety of reasons.

How can I accomplish this? I tried to use `cmd` to rename `Skrivbord` to `Desktop`, but then I keep getting error messages from the shell all the time. I also tried to use Explorer to rename it, but then - of course - the displaed name changes, but not the real name (that is, the opposite of what I want). What can I do?

Comment: Although unrelated, I wonder what the `.bat` files are used for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a [directory junction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point) using [mklink](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194(WS.10).aspx), this will reparse every action from *Desktop* to access *Skrivbord*.

Open up a [command prompt](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Command-Prompt-frequently-asked-questions) and execute:

```
mklink /j %HOMEPATH%\Desktop %HOMEPATH%\Skrivbord
```

Comment: This works for my needs. Still, it is a bit ugly that `Desktop` works in a different way than the other folders (that still have names in English), but that is just pedantics, I guess.